# Use luxon to loop between two dates to create a time interval

Tags: javascript, datetime, luxon

I have UTC dates stored in a collection like so:

```json
"orderBeforeStartTime" : ISODate("2021-03-20T14:00:00.000Z"),
"orderBeforeEndTime" : ISODate("2021-03-20T16:00:00.000Z")
```

I want to do a loop that starts at `orderBeforeStartTime` and ends at `orderBeforeEndTime` to populate an array with time intervals.

So for example using the above data, I should get an array as such:

```js
['14:00', '14:30', '15:00', '15:30', '16:00'];
```

There should be 30 minutes interval between each number until I reach `orderBeforeEndTime`.

My code:

```js
const { DateTime } = require("luxon");
let startDate;

const endDate = DateTime.fromHTTP(
    item.timeSegment.orderBeforeEndTime.toUTCString()
);

if (new Date() > item.timeSegment.orderBeforeStartTime) {
    startDate = DateTime.utc();
} else {
    startDate = DateTime.fromHTTP(
    item.timeSegment.orderBeforeStartTime.toUTCString()
    );
}

while (startDate <= endDate) {
    item.orderTimeSegments.push(
    startDate.toLocaleString(DateTime.TIME_24_SIMPLE)
    );
    startDate = startDate.plus({ minutes: 30 });
}
```

Is this the correct way to do it?

Comment: Have you read [the documentation](https://moment.github.io/luxon/docs/class/src/datetime.js~DateTime.html#instance-method-plus)? There's a `plus` method that will add a duration to the date. Make a duration of 30 minutes, add it to `orderBeforeStartTime` until it becomes `orderBeforeEndTime`...

Comment: Thanks, I updated my post with the code to check if my logic is sound

Answer (score 7):

Based on the [documentation](https://moment.github.io/luxon/api-docs/index.html#intervalsplitby), there is a way to iterate on the Interval given a `DurationObjectUnits`.

```js
const start = new Date("2021-03-20T14:00:00.000Z");
const end = new Date("2021-03-20T16:00:00.000Z");

const interval = Interval.fromDateTimes(
  DateTime.fromJSDate(start),
  DateTime.fromJSDate(end)
);

const desiredArray = interval.splitBy({ minutes: 30 }).map((d) => d.start);
```

Possible splits

```
export interface DurationObjectUnits {
    year?: number | undefined;
    years?: number | undefined;
    quarter?: number | undefined;
    quarters?: number | undefined;
    month?: number | undefined;
    months?: number | undefined;
    week?: number | undefined;
    weeks?: number | undefined;
    day?: number | undefined;
    days?: number | undefined;
    hour?: number | undefined;
    hours?: number | undefined;
    minute?: number | undefined;
    minutes?: number | undefined;
    second?: number | undefined;
    seconds?: number | undefined;
    millisecond?: number | undefined;
    milliseconds?: number | undefined;
}
```

Comment: Too many pending edits, so here's the updated link to the docs: https://moment.github.io/luxon/api-docs/index.html#intervalsplitby